# Delete documents by prefix from elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have JSON documents with the below format and I would like to delete documents that have any `id` starting with `users_`.

```
{
"id": "users_1",
"name": "Adam"
}
```

One approach is to get all documents using wildcard then delete their IDs but this would require two requests. Is there a way to delete using a wildcard on a single field?

The solution I've tried is

```
requests.post(
    'https://<some-project>.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io/api/as/v1/engines/<project-name>/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed&pretty',
    headers=header, 
    data=json.dumps({
        "query": {
            "match_all": {"ids": "users_*"}
        }
    })
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your `id` mapping, the `prefix` query should work too:

```
.../_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "id": {
        "value": "users_"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you should use the delete by query API (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) which lets you (you guessed it!) delete documents that match a query rather than having to know their document id's in advance.

I'd recommend using the prefix-query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) for your particular use case. This however requires your id-field to be mapped as text in order to perform fulltext searches.

I hope I could help you.